# ContainsKey on TreeMap throws NPE

Tags: java, comparator, treemap

So i have a `Comparator` that i defined for my `TreeMap` to sort it by values,
but when i use `containsKey(anyKey)` on a key that it does not contain it doesn't return false, but it throws a `NullPointerException`. Now what i don't understand is why it goes in my Comparator for the `containsKey()` method and how i could find a solution... I've been stuck on this for a couple of hours and any help would be appriciated.

Here is the code :

```
public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        HashMap<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put(1,2);
        map.put(2, 3);
        Comparator<Integer> comp = new ValueComparator<Integer, Integer>(map);
        TreeMap<Integer, Integer> tm = new TreeMap<Integer, Integer>(comp);
        tm.putAll(map);
        System.out.println(tm.containsKey(1)); // returns true
        System.out.println(tm.containsKey(3)); //Throws NPE
    }


}

class ValueComparator<K, V extends Comparable<V>> implements Comparator<K>{

    HashMap<K, V> map = new HashMap<K, V>();

    public ValueComparator(HashMap<K, V> map){
        this.map.putAll(map);
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(K s1, K s2) {

        return map.get(s1).compareTo(map.get(s2));//descending order    
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your stack trace

Comment: Actually it's pretty obvious. Your `compare()` method doesn't check if the key is in the map. You need to decide how to handle unmapped keys.

Comment: containsKey needs to compare the value you're checking to the values in the tree, but 3 isn't in the map you've fed to your comparator

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner That makes no sense.

Comment: Well i understand that i don't check if it's in my map(so get returns null) but what do if it's not in my map than ? (I'm new to these structures and maybe not sure how all this works so sorry if this seems a bit dumb) Thanks for the answers

Comment: @NoobieErrors That's a requirements question. Only you can answer that.

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner That compares *what*?

Comment: @NoobieErrors What to do when a key is not in the map? Short answer: your comparator must not return 0, because that's how `TreeMap` checks if a key belongs to the map. According to `TreeMap` docs: a sorted map performs all key comparisons using its compareTo (or compare) method

Comment: @shmosel thanks a lot, makes a bit more sense now :)

Answer (score -1):

```
@Override
public int compare(K s1, K s2) {
    // Here is the problem you need to check if map.get(s1) returns null.
    return map.get(s1).compareTo(map.get(s2));//descending order    
}
```